# namespaceを維持したまま外部モジュールとして他のファイルから読み込むには

Tags: node.js, typescript

- 環境

  - Node.js:8.9.4
  - typescript:2.9.2
- やりたいこと

  - 名前空間内のクラスをjestやmochaでテストしたい
  - tsconfig.jsonのtargetはES5
  - ソース側は変更したくない
- 現状の例

  ```
  // src/main.ts
  namespace base {
      export class Foo {
          constructor() { console.log("Called Foo Constructor!"); }
          public answerToTheUltimateQuestion(): number { return 42; }
          public callHello() { return new Bar().say() }
      }
  }

  // src/Hello.ts
  namespace base {
      export class Bar {
          constructor() { console.log("Called Bar Constructor!"); };
          say(): string { return "hello!"; }
          getFoo() { return new base.Foo(); }
      }
  }

  // \__tests__/main.test.ts
  const foo = new base.Foo(); // ReferenceError: base is not defined

  test("someMethod", () => {
      expect(foo.answerToTheUltimateQuestion()).toBe(42);
  });
  ```

モジュール形式に書き直すのが一番良いとはわかっているのですが、ファイル数が多く、
変更しづらい状況なため、どうにかしてまずテストで
壊れてもわかる状況を確保してから書き直していきたいのです。
d.tsファイル、tsconfig.jsonのtarget以外の変更、あるいは他の手段で解決することはできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

本家のstackoverflowに同様の質問がありました。ただし、本家の質問は解決にいたっていません。

[How would I test Typescript code that uses namespaces in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952139/how-would-i-test-typescript-code-that-uses-namespaces-in-node-js?answertab=active#tab-top)

ただその中で、TypeScriptの`--outFile` オプションを使う方式が紹介されていました。

以下のようにテストコードに`/// <reference />`で依存関係のあるファイルパスを記載し、
`outFile`オプションに`main.test.js`などと指定して、
テストコードと依存コードを1つまとめれば、テストコードの修正と、
ビルドツールの工夫だけで対応できるかもしれません。

```
// \__tests__/main.test.ts
/// <reference path="main.ts" />
/// <reference path="Hello.ts" />
const foo = new base.Foo(); // ReferenceError: base is not defined

test("someMethod", () => {
    expect(foo.answerToTheUltimateQuestion()).toBe(42);
});
```